# Windows XP deleted Windows 8 bootloader

Tags: ubuntu, windows-xp, windows-8, partitioning, bootloader

I bought a new computer which came with Windows 8 preinstalled. Then I installed Ubuntu 12.04 on the same hard drive, after making a partition with GParted using the "Try Ubuntu" option in the Ubuntu installer. Everything worked fine, I had Windows 8 and Ubuntu working together without any issue.

The problem comes when I decided to install Windows XP alongside with Windows 8 and Ubuntu. It seems that Windows XP deleted the GRUB bootloader, so now I can't boot any OS, there's no Ubuntu option, no Windows 8 option, nothing. Just the message "Read error" (translated from Spanish). I successfully reinstalled GRUB, using the Ubuntu live CD and running some commands from the terminal following a recovery guide, so now I'm writing this from my Ubuntu system, but there's no way to run Windows 8. Now when I select the "Windows 8 Loader" option it says `Read error. Press Ctrl+Alt+Delete to reboot`.

So how can I recover the access to Windows 8?

Comment: @gladiator2345 - That simply is not true.  The key is embedded into the bios even if the partition is delete his key is safe.

Comment: Windows 8 does not support installing alongside XP.

Answer (score 0):

Put in your Windows 8 DVD or use a flash as a boot device.

Boot into the Windows installation, click Troubleshoot > click Advanced options > choose Automatic Repair.

Else, after opening Advanced options choose Command prompt and type: bootrec /fixboot

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't have the Windows 8 DVD.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers. I solved this using the Boot-Repair tool, following [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair). This tool automatically fixed the Windows 8 loader.

Comment: Yes :LOL:, I can't accept it now, it tells my that I will be able to accept it tomorrow :-)